# Any Example of Android Public API being removed

Tags: android, api, android-framework

I was going through the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) and I came across below lines:

> In a very small number of cases, parts of the API may be modified or
> removed, although typically such changes are only needed to ensure API
> robustness and application or system security.

Is there an example of such removal of `public` API?

It would be interesting insight for all of us, developers, to understand why an API is removed and what can possibly be removed in Future based on this previous **history**.

Comment: Each Android SDK release comes with a differences report, such as [this one for API 20->21](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes.html). Each shows you the removed items via strikethrough formatting, and there is a dedicated link in the frameset to filter the differences to only show the removals.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache HTTP client was deprecated in API 22 and [removed in API 23](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).  In this case it appears that they only removed it from the stub library, so apps using it will still run on Android M.  You just can't *compile* them for Android M.

Google has also effectively removed features by changing the way APIs work.  An example of this was the change to [`ActivityManager#getRunningTasks(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) in API 21.  The method is still there, but it no longer allows you to discover what other apps are running, which is what many developers were using it for.  Another example is how network activity on the main thread started throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in Android 3.0.  In both of these examples, the documentation described the intended use of the API long before they began enforcing it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! But is there a place where such info is maintained by Google or any other developer community? I checked the "Behavior changes" link that you posted and it seems it is applicable as of M Developer preview. So, shall we need to check release notes of each release to find any REMOVED API?

Comment: @AADTechnical Yes, unfortunately you have to read the change notes for every release.  Google is very bad about not including differences between API versions in the documentation.  For example, there have been so many bugs in `AudioTrack` that it's practically impossible to write code that works across a wide range of Android versions.  But none of the workarounds are mentioned in the docs.  You have to dig through old bug reports and SO answers to find them.

Comment: You can check the comments section below the question where Mark Murphy gave a link where API Diff. are available. I checked the link and it shows the REMOVED APIs too. Of course, it is for release between 2 API Level.